# how to mock this.$refs.form.validate in vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a vue code where i do some actions based on this.$refs.form.validate 
I wanted to write a test for it ...But not sure how can i mock this.$refs.form.validate? I have written only basic ones..can someone point me at right direction?I am using Vue+Jest

```
methods: {
        sayHello () {

          if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
            //code goes here
    }
```

Is there a way to make it return false and true?

Answer (score 3):

create a stub

```
const VueFormStub = {
 render: () => {},
 methods: {
  validate: () => {}
 }
}
```

then in your wrapper add it like this

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(VueFile, {
 stubs: {
  'v-form': VueFormStub
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What is strange `$refs` don't seem to work inside `mocks` property when we mount a component in a test. But if we do like this it works

```
const wrapper = mount(SidePanel);
wrapper.vm.$refs.checkbox = [{ focused: false }, { focused: true }];
```

So when component does something like this it will be ok

```
console.log(this.$refs.checkbox[0].focused);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use jest method `jest.fn()` to mock your function. Like so `const foo = jest.fn()`. And the you need to test, if this fn has been called.

Comment: Write [stub](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#stubs) of this ref component and note this validate method inside. Next use this stub when mounting component.
`stubs: {
  form: { 
    render(h) { return h('div') },
    methods: {
      validate() {}
    }
  }
}
`